# C programming: How to deprecate INLINE function

Tags: c, deprecated

How to deprecate `__STATIC_INLINE` function. I know that I have to use `__attribute__ ((deprecated))` but how to use it for the following function:

```
__STATIC_INLINE void Foo()
{
  ...
}
```

Update:
My goal is to use a `#define` that declare the deprecation attribute like:
`#define THIS_IS_DEPRECATED __attribute__ ((deprecated))`

and use the #define to deprecate APIs.

Update 2: Proposed solution worked 50% if I use:

```
__STATIC_INLINE void THIS_IS_DEPRECATED Foo()
{
  ...
}
```

Now I am getting the deprecation warning, but another error appeared:

```
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'Foo'
  428 | __STATIC_INLINE void THIS_IS_DEPRECATED Foo(void)
      |                                         ^~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Doesn't `__attribute__ ((deprecated)) __STATIC_INLINE void Foo()` work?

Comment: No :( it does not work, I think attribute should be in the end.

Comment: `want to use the attribute within a #define like: #define THIS_IS_DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated)) and use the #define instead.` So use it, why are you asking here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static inline __attribute__((deprecated)) void Foo()
{
  
}
```

works for me. It generates a warning when I try to use it.

However I am not sure what the `__STATIC_INLINE` is?

EDIT according to your comment:

Do you mean something like

```
#define THIS_IS_DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))

static inline THIS_IS_DEPRECATED void Foo()
{
  
}
```

Comment: yes that actually works, but I think I did not post the whole problem.
actually I want to use the attribute within a #define like: `#define THIS_IS_DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))` and use the #define instead.

I just updated the post

Comment: I think the edit in your question should work?

Comment: `not sure what the __STATIC_INLINE is?` Coudl be anything, but it's conincence same macro is in ARM CMSIS libraries: https://github.com/mikeferguson/stm32/blob/master/libraries/CMSIS/Include/core_cm3.h#L67 . || Anyway it's odd to put attribute between return type and function name, I would put it in front. `static inline __attribute__((__deprecated__)) rettype function();`. Also https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html

Comment: @KamilCuk I agree, that would be better, I will edit my awnser

Comment: that works but now I am getting another error
`error: expected ';' before 'void'
  415 | __STATIC_INLINE THIS_IS_DEPRECATED void Foo(bool enable) `

Comment: can you share a minimal reproducer?